# iOS in app subscription infinite purchase group for same product

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I have an in app subscription design question.

I would like to create an application which should contain a single “purchase group” but this “purchase group” may have to be purchase multiple time.

I explain:

I have a single user who can create a group and invite other users to this group.
On each group he created he can purchase a single product (which different pricing). But this single product can be purchase for each group he created.
Unfortunately I can’t let him buy this product multiple time for each group since he can subscribe for only one product by “purchase group”. And I can’t multiply “purchase group” with this product in App Store Connect since a user can create as many groups as he want.

So I wonder how I should setup this kind of scenario.

Comment: It sounds like these are either consumable or non-renewing subscription products. You can't use auto renewing subscriptions

Comment: for each group it's subscription, I and need them to auto renew

Comment: Your use case doesn't sound like a good fit for auto-renewing subscriptions.  You could have a tiered model where a user could subscribe for "1 group" or "2 groups" or "5 groups" etc, but your pricing varies for each group so I don't think that would work for you.  You could create multiple subscription groups so that the user could purchase one subscription from multiple groups at different price tiers but I think that would be very confusing for the user to manage.